# Kivy: Updating a Label-Text letter by letter via interval doesn't work

Tags: python, kivy

I am deperately trying to create a "typewriter" effect in a Kivy Label. The Text 'That is my sample text' below should fill my label letter by letter with a 0.5 interval between each letter. Just like someone typing it with a type writer.

However the result i get is weird: Instead of getting the desired effect, the whole string is added after 0.5 and thats it. It seems like my for-loop is completely ignored.

Any idea what I can do?

That's my class TestScreen(Screen):

```
def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
    super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    my_box = FloatLayout()

    self.mylabel = Label(
            text='',
            font_size=26,
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.05})

    my_box.add_widget(self.mylabel)
    self.add_widget(my_box)

    for letter in 'That is my sample text':
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.setLetterByLetter, letter=letter), 1)

def setLetterByLetter(self, dt, letter):
    self.mylabel.text += letter
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question

> get the text starting in the upper left corner of the label

## Solution - text in top-left corner

Add the following in the constructor, `__init__()` method.

```
def __init__(self, string, **kwargs):
    super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.bind(size=self.setter('text_size'))
    self.halign = 'left'
    self.valign = 'top'
```

[Text alignment and wrapping](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#text-alignment-and-wrapping)

> The [Label](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label) has [halign](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign) and [valign](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.valign) properties to control the alignment of
>   its text. However, by default the text image ([texture](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.texture)) is only just
>   large enough to contain the characters and is positioned in the center
>   of the Label. The valign property will have no effect and halign will
>   only have an effect if your text has newlines; a single line of text
>   will appear to be centered even though halign is set to left (by
>   default).
>
> In order for the alignment properties to take effect, set the
>   [text_size](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size), which specifies the size of the bounding box within which
>   text is aligned. For instance, the following code binds this size to
>   the size of the Label, so text will be aligned within the widget
>   bounds. This will also automatically wrap the text of the Label to
>   remain within this area.
>
> ```
> Label:
>     text_size: self.size
>     halign: 'right'
>     valign: 'middle'
> ```

## Output - text in top-left corner

[image: Img01 - text in top-left corner]
[image: Img02 - text in top-left corner]

## Solution - text in center

Using `Clock.create_trigger()` to simulate a typewriter.

[Triggered Events](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#triggered-events)

> A triggered event is a way to defer a callback. It functions exactly
>   like schedule_once() and schedule_interval() except that it doesn’t
>   immediately schedule the callback. Instead, one schedules the callback
>   using the [ClockEvent](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.ClockEvent) returned by it. This ensures that you can
>   call the event multiple times but it won’t be scheduled more than
>   once. This is not the case with Clock.schedule_once()

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


class TestScreen(Label):

    def __init__(self, string, **kwargs):
        super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = 26
        self.string = string
        self.typewriter = Clock.create_trigger(self.typeit, 1)
        self.typewriter()

    def typeit(self, dt):
        self.text += self.string[0]
        self.string = self.string[1:]
        if len(self.string) > 0:
            self.typewriter()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Typewriter"

    def build(self):
        return TestScreen("That is my Kivy Typewriter demo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output - text in center

[image: Img01 - text in center]
[image: Img02 - text in center]

Comment: Hi ikolim: It almost worked. However the "typwriter-text" is somehow centered. I spend the whole evening to get the text starting in the upper left corner of the label, but it never worked when I try to use halign=left & valign=top. I also tried to set text_size = size like it was described in the docs. No success.

Comment: Please refer to updated post for placing text in top-left corner of Label widget.

Comment: thx. I just figured out that I had to do that binding here to make the position work:

self.my_label.bind(size=self.my_label.setter('text_size'))

Answer (score 0):

## **Don't need to use `kwargs`**

To create a typewriter effect, just follow the code below.

```
def anything(str):

for letter in str:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)

anything("That is my sample text.")
```

The code I've written gives a 0.5 second waiting time between every letter in the string, and only takes six lines of code.